# react-select Adjust the font displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using the pre-build react-select library, which is a standard auto complete drop-down syle library, however i cannot find how to adjust the font. The current font is generic, and I would like to adjust it. I do not usually use a .css file, and would prefer to classify it through a prop.

For example current:

```
const JobPostSkillsValued = () => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
    

  return (
    <PrimaryContentContainer>
        <PayContainerDropdown>
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" marginBottom="15px"> 
                Pay typerr
            </Typography>
            <GeneralSkillsDropDownContainer>
              <Select

                closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                components={animatedComponents}
                defaultValue={[colourOptions[4], colourOptions[5]]}
                isMulti
                options={colourOptions}
                onChange={setSelectedOption}
                
              />
            </GeneralSkillsDropDownContainer>


        </PayContainerDropdown>
    </PrimaryContentContainer>
  )
}

export default JobPostSkillsValued
```

How would I set the font family, size etc?

Comment: https://react-select.com/styles

Answer (score 0):

As @technophyle mentioned above, provide a custom `styleFn`. I would suggest at the `container` level, which should cascade down to all internal components, though you could potentially have to do other containers as well.

```js
const customStyles = {
  container: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    font: // your font declaration
  })
};
// ...
<Select
  styles={customStyles}
  {...otherProps}
/>
```

Comment: Hi @Steve, I appreciate the comment. Would this be notes as: ```            <GeneralSkillsDropDownContainer>
              <Select

                closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                components={animatedComponents}
                defaultValue={[colourOptions[0], colourOptions[1]]}
                isMulti
                // styles={customStyles}
                options={colourOptions}
                onChange={setSelectedOption}
                styles={customStyles}
                
              />
            </GeneralSkillsDropDownContainer>```

Comment: looks right, but hard to tell with complete code.